# Updating StateObject from the View and expecting changes back to the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ListView with a list of users; tapping on each item takes me to the Detail page.

### ListView

```
NavigationStack {
    List {
        ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
            NavigationLink(value: user) {
                Text(user.givenName)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("UserList")
    .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
        FormView(user) // this gets called twice, annoying but no solution yet. 
    })
```

### FormView

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        HStack {
            TextField("First", text: Binding(
                    get: { viewModel.user.first ?? "" },
                    set: { viewModel.user.first = $0 }))
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                          
            TextField("Middle", text: Binding(
                    get: { viewModel.user.last ?? "" },
                    set: { viewModel.user.last = $0 }))
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .autocapitalization(.none)

             ...
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        viewModel.setUser(user) // deferred set, to ensure ObservableObject is created
        // viewModel.user = user // perhaps its not good to set directly
    }
    ...

var user: User
      
init(_ user: User) {
    self.user = user // received the user from the list page
    // viewModel.user = user // forbidden by XCode, doesn't compile
}
```

The user comes from the List page, and I assign it to a local variable first and wait for the view to appear before I set it on the viewModel.

on the ViewModel side, upon breakpoint, I do see that the user was passed and set, only the View is not updating.

### ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     
    @Published var user: User = User(id: 0)

    func setUser(_ user: User) {
        self.user = user // user 
        objectWillChange.send() // forcing update - no use
    }
```

---

### Question

1. Main Question is if a change was pushed from `View` to the `ObservableObject` and a reaction was expected back in the `View`, how to do in context of my question.
2. This gets called twice on the tap from the list page, another dilemma.

--

```
 .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
     FormView(user) // this gets called twice, annoying but no solution yet. 
 })
```

---

### Edit - This worked, really?

```
.onAppear {
    // viewModel.setUser(user)
    // viewModel.user = user
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        viewModel.user = user
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have multiple instances of `ViewModel`. You need to pass the same instance from `ListView` into `FormView` -- not create a _new_ one inside `FormView`

Comment: you don't have to do `objectWillChange.send` after `user` is updated since user is a published property.

Comment: Try removing the ViewModel since that is what the View struct is for already

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have multiple instances of `ViewModel`. You need to pass the same instance from ListView into FormView -- not create a new one inside `FormView`.

So, in `FormView`, you would replace

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

with

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
```

It would end up like:

```
struct FormView: View {
  var user: User
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View { ... }
}
```

and the call site would look like:

```
FormView(user: user, viewModel: viewModel)
```

Then, get rid of `objectWillChange.send()`, which isn't useful here -- you're already doing that by setting a `@Published` property.

Finally, unless there's really a need for a view model here, it would probably be easier to replace this with `@State` and `@Binding`, but that's out of the scope of this direct question.

Comment: Actually let me clarify, Not multiple instances but I have separate ViewModels for each. `ListViewModel`, `FormViewModel`, and I understand your strategy here is to use one single shared `ViewModel` instance for both screens. I'll have a problem with scalability there, what if i have 10 or more screens in a navController, it will just bloat and explode the shared `viewModel`

Comment: The principal is still the same -- you have to have _some_ point where you do communication and that must be owned at the highest level point. I answered the question best I could given the code you provided, but it sounds like there's more code that changes the scope of the question. I suggest you include a [mre]

Comment: Also, I disagree that 10 screens will "will just bloat and explode the shared viewModel" -- it sounds like you need need _one_ place to store a `User`... there should be a single source of truth for that

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: I don't know why your edit works, because I can't run your code. If you include a [mre], I could see what's happening

Comment: Is there an online playground for swift UI where I can create and share minimalistic examples?

Comment: You can use Xcode. Create a minimal example and paste the code into your question.

Comment: @Source if you just post the exact code you have that runs, we can try to debug it a little better. We are missing pieces of information that would make reproducing easier

Comment: @yonodactyl I would necessary suggest posting "the exact code" -- it's up to the OP to remove unnecessary code that doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: I'll follow that for my next question, especially for this double call issue on the `navigationDestination`

Comment: @jnpdx of course, discretion with IP is expected - I just mean that the ListView is referencing a VM and we dont even know how its set up - a minimum reproducible example would help for sure